# Using 2 instances of same partial view on a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

On my page I am using 2 instances of the same PartialView as

```
<div>
        @Html.Partial("AddressPartial1", Model.Address1)   
</div>
<div>                                           
        @Html.Partial("AddressPartial2", Model.Address2) 
</div>
```

I am able to get unique id for all my fields in the PartialView for both instances by passing the InstanceName and concatenating it to the field names. Now the issue is when I post my page I am not getting the model object for both my views. I can read the values of the controls using FormCollection but I was looking for a better solution to my scenario of using 2 instances of PartialView on the same page.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

Model(For my Page):

```
Private m_Address1 As New AddressModel("Address1")
    Public Property Address1() As AddressModel
        Get
            Return m_Address1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As AddressModel)
            m_Address1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

   Private m_Address2 As New AddressModel("Address2")
    Public Property Address2 () As AddressModel
        Get
            Return m_Address2 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As AddressModel)
            m_Address2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Model for PartialView:

```
Public Class AddressModel
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ModelInstanceName As String)
        m_ModelInstanceName = ModelInstanceName
    End Sub

    Private m_ModelInstanceName As String
Private m_StreetAddress1 As String
    Private m_StreetAddress2 As String
    Private m_City As String
    Private m_State As String
    Private m_ZipCode As String

Public Property ModelInstanceName As String
        Get
            Return m_ModelInstanceName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ModelInstanceName = value
        End Set
    End Property

Public Property StreetAddress1() As String
        Get
            Return m_StreetAddress1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If (value IsNot Nothing) Then value = value.Trim()
            If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) Then value = Nothing

            m_StreetAddress1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

and other properties....

Partial View:

```
@ModelType AddressModel
<table style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 99%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="editor-label">
                <span class="required">@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.StreetAddress1)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBox(Model.ModelInstanceName + "_StreetAddress1", Model.StreetAddress1, New With {.style = "width:390px"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.StreetAddress1)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBox(Model.ModelInstanceName + "_StreetAddress2", Model.StreetAddress2, New With {.style = "width:390px"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.StreetAddress2)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

<tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <span class="required">@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.ZipCode)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBox(Model.ModelInstanceName + "_ZipCode", Model.ZipCode, New With {.style = "width:60px", .maxlength = "5", .onblur = "zipchange('" + Model.ModelInstanceName + "')"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ZipCode)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <span class="required">@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.City)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBox(Model.ModelInstanceName + "_City", Model.City, New With {.style = "width:130px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.City)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and so on...

Comment: Please post the code for your controller POST action, your partial view and your models.

Comment: You are not using the same PartialView. You are using AddressPartial1 and AddressPartial2 that are different for MVC

Comment: oops my mistake .. i am using same PartialView.i.e. AddressPartial

Answer (score 1):

Real old one but I just ran into the same problem.
There is a simple article [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/fe1c187c-9d93-4c48-89dc-e497c2a53294.aspx) which explains the problem and the solution.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
 @{ Html.Partial("AddressPartial", Model.Address, new ViewDataDictionary()
   {
       TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address1" }
   }); }

 @{ Html.Partial("AddressPartial", Model.Address, new ViewDataDictionary()
   {
       TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address2" }
   }); }
```

This will add the necessary prefix to control ids, etc and bind correctly when you post back. (assuming the supplied prefixes match your property names)